# calculate date difference between today's date and pandas date series

Tags: python, pandas

Want to calculate the difference of days between pandas date series -

```
0      2013-02-16
1      2013-01-29
2      2013-02-21
3      2013-02-22
4      2013-03-01
5      2013-03-14
6      2013-03-18
7      2013-03-21
```

and today's date.

I tried but could not come up with logical solution.
Please help me with the code. Actually I am new to python and there are lot of syntactical errors happening while applying any function.

Comment: Use `(ser-pd.datetime.today()).dt.days` here ser is your series of datatype datetime.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please add a [mcve] and what you tried.

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like

```
# generate time data
data = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["2018-09-1", "2019-01-25", "2018-10-10"]))
pd.to_datetime("now") > data
```

returns:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
```

you could then use that to select the data

```
data[pd.to_datetime("now") > data]
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: I misread it but you can easily alter this example to calculate the difference:

```
data -  pd.to_datetime("now")
```

returns:

```
0   -122 days +13:10:37.489823
1      24 days 13:10:37.489823
2    -83 days +13:10:37.489823
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try as Follows:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df
        col1
0 2013-02-16
1 2013-01-29
2 2013-02-21
3 2013-02-22
4 2013-03-01
5 2013-03-14
6 2013-03-18
7 2013-03-21
```

Make Sure to convert the column names to_datetime:

```
>>> df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

set the current datetime in order to Further get the diffrence:

```
>>> curr_time = pd.to_datetime("now")
```

Now get the Difference as follows:

```
>>> df['col1'] - curr_time
0   -2145 days +07:48:48.736939
1   -2163 days +07:48:48.736939
2   -2140 days +07:48:48.736939
3   -2139 days +07:48:48.736939
4   -2132 days +07:48:48.736939
5   -2119 days +07:48:48.736939
6   -2115 days +07:48:48.736939
7   -2112 days +07:48:48.736939
Name: col1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: @Shivam, Glad it helped, To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in,    You can check   [ guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

With numpy you can solve it like [difference-two-dates-days-weeks-months-years-pandas-python-2](http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/difference-two-dates-days-weeks-months-years-pandas-python-2/)
. bottom line

```
df['diff_days'] = df['First dates column'] - df['Second Date column']

# for days use 'D' for weeks use 'W', for month use 'M' and for years use 'Y'
df['diff_days']=df['diff_days']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')      
print(df)
```

if you want days as int and not as float use

```
df['diff_days']=df['diff_days']//np.timedelta64(1,'D')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the pandas docs under [Converting To Timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps) you will find:

"*Converting to Timestamps To convert a Series or list-like object of date-like objects e.g. strings, epochs, or a mixture, you can use the `to_datetime` function*"

I haven't used pandas before but this suggests your pandas date series (a list-like object) is iterable and each element of this series is an instance of a class which has a `to_datetime` function.

Assuming my assumptions are correct, the following function would take such a list and return a list of timedeltas' (a datetime object representing the difference between two date time objects).

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert(pandas_series):
    # get the current date
    now = datetime.now()

    # Use a list comprehension and the pandas to_datetime method to calculate timedeltas.
    return [now - pandas_element.to_datetime() for pandas_series]

# assuming 'some_pandas_series' is a list-like pandas series object
list_of_timedeltas = convert(some_pandas_series)
```